# Can post-data be sent and received partially, e.g. only headers and not content?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, backend

I have a simple web app using jQuery to send ajax post-requests, and one of them contains user identification in the header and the data to store in the data section.

My question is simply if it is possible during some weird network conditions that the transmission is received partially but still processed, so that for instance the headers are sent but the form data is empty? In that case the backend might think that the user performed a request but had no changes to make (which is incorrect).

If that is the case, what is the best way on the backend to ensure that full request is received? A checksum/hash? Checking content-length?

The backend is PHP and server i Windows Azure, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I've never experienced anything like that during all my years as a web developer, so I would say no. That's not something you need to worry about. If you experience something like that, there's probably something else that's wrong.

Comment: You always need to do server side validation anyway since client side data can't be trusted. As for a partial request like you describe that is highly unlikely

Comment: Thank you. @charlietfl Server-side validation is done of course. When you say "highly unlikely", do you mean like finding a sha256-collision (i.e. practically impossible) or like 1 in a million? The latter is a serious problem in our case.

Comment: If $_POST is empty reject the request and log error on both ends so you can track down why